# Reload entire fragment on backpress

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an `AppCompatActivity` that let the users to draw signature then the activity passes the Path of the signature to a `fragment`. The `fragment` is supposed to put the signature on an `ImageView`. The `fragment` is receiving the path of the image precisely correct. For test, when i put the path manually the `ImageView` shows up the image very finely on App Startup. but after having drawn the signature from the activity, the image is not showing up on the `fragment`.
 After digging in a lot and lots of FAQs on stackoverflow i came to know that the `fragment` components are not refreshing after `backpress` from the `activity`. There is a terms and condition checkbox on the `fragment`. Even that `checkbox` remains checked after getting back from the `activity`. Spent hours in this solving this. No luck.

**Activity Side coding to pass the Image Path-**

```
Menu1_SecondClass fragment = new Menu1_SecondClass(); 
fragment.setBoolean(true);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("imagePath", StoredPath);  // Passing the Path
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.linearLayout, fragment);
ft.commit();

finish();
mFileOutStream.flush();
mFileOutStream.close();
```

**Fragment Side Coding**

```
public class Menu1_SecondClass extends Fragment {
    Button signatureButton;
    ImageView signImage;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    View view;
    public String image_path;
    public boolean vboolean = false;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Homework Details");
    }
    public void setBoolean(Boolean boo){
        this.vboolean = boo;
    }
    public boolean getBoolean(){
        return this.vboolean;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getBoolean()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refreshing.. " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.setBoolean(false);
            refreshFragment();
        }
    }

    public void refreshFragment(){
        FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.setReorderingAllowed(false);
        t.detach(this).attach(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_homework, container, false);

        signatureButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getSign);
        signImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSign);
        signatureButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        //disable button if checkbox is not checked else enable button
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    signatureButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    signatureButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        putSignature();

        return view;
    }

    public void putSignature(){

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        if (bundle != null) {
            image_path = bundle.getString("imagePath", "");                if(!image_path.isEmpty()) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    //bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 80, false);
                    signImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Created: " + image_path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Null Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SignatureActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                signatureButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When You are passing data from `activity` to `fragment` you can use below code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("imagePath", imagePath);
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and while receiving data in `fragment`, inside `onCreateView` method you can write code like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("imagePath");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.framelay_loan, firstFrag);
transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("imagePath", imagePath);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.commit();`
```

Inside onCreateView method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_micro_form1, container,false);
      Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            image_path = bundle.getString("imagePath", ""); 
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Not working. Image is still not loading on ImageView.

Comment: Did you print "image_path" value? Is it null?

Comment: What is the result for "image_path"?

Comment: I'm receiving the path absolutely correct. I have checked the path manually. No problem on that side.